# Multiple terminals instantiated, scrollback not working on invisible terminals

Tags: xtermjs

With multiple xterm.js terminals instantiated in the browser, each in a visible div at time of creation (so correctly sized and working), we send a command to each remote shell (e.g. history) and get the response correctly into each of the terminals.  Only one terminal is visible at the time the return occurs.  For the visible terminal, full scrollback works (assuming the response is > number of rows visible).  For the invisible terminals, the response is cropped at the first visible line (so no scrollback capable).

Have tried different terminals being visible (first, middle, last) and only the visible terminal supports scrollback, all others crop at the top visible line.  If one of the other terminals is made visible, and the command re-run (e.g. history), scrollback works fine (although never past the first visible line it showed before).  If the command does not return line count > max visible lines then there is no need for scrollback (and hence no issue).

Is there any way to overcome this?  It's not possible to focus each terminal as the information comes in as it could be in parallel.

Comment: I am also interested in this question. In my case, the app provides user-defined command tabs, and each can have an xterm terminal. Launching a command creates a node-pty child process which runs, and while a view is visible (e.g. active tab), an xterm terminal connects to its node-pty process to show its output. Naturally, in this concept only one view can be active. So.. whenever you switch to a different view, you only get "live updates". I can collect the output somehow, the question is how to initialize the xterm view with pre-existing data..